# What does "Please set program to run!" means in PHPStorm?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have the following message when trying to add a new file watcher. Still can't find the solution. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: You need to fill the `program` field with the full path to the program that will be called by this file watcher (in your case it's supposed to be SCSS compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to compile SCSS to CSS, you need to install the SASS compiler (gem install sass) and configure it as a file watcher for .scss files (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d128637e458)

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this in the newest version of the IDE as well. Would like to mention that another possibly overlooked thing (as is my case), was the execution bit in chmod. I had the script but didn't give myself the exec privilege.